# Rank-$1$ matrices and the inequality $\operatorname{rank} (A+B) \leq \operatorname{rank} (A) + \operatorname{rank} (B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, alternative-proof, matrix-rank

I am interested in a proof of the inequality $$\operatorname{rank} (A+B) \leq \operatorname{rank} (A) + \operatorname{rank} (B)$$ that does **not** use the bases of $A$'s and $B$'s row/column spaces, as described in other answers on this site. My idea is to use rank-$1$ matrices.

So, the proof is: write the matrices $A$ and $B$ as sums of matrices of rank 1. It is known that any matrix $M$ can be written as a sum of at least $rank(M)$ matrices of rank 1. Thus, the decomposition of $A+B$ will have at least $rank(A)+rank(B)$ matrix terms. This decomposition is also a decomposition of $A+B$. Now it's straightforward to see that $rank(A+B) \leq rank(A) + rank(B)$, QED.

Is such a proof valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's valid, it just needs some work to be more strict.

The sentence "any matrix $M$ can be written as a sum of at least $rank(M)$ matrices of rank $1$" is slightly misleading, as in fact, you know (and use) ***two*** things about sums of rank $1$ matrices:

1. It is possible to write $M$ as a sum of $rank(M)$ rank-one matrices
2. If $M=R_1 + R_2 + \cdots + R_n$ where $R_i$ are rank-one, then $n\geq rank(M)$.

In your proof, you first write $A$ and $B$ as sums of $rank(A)$ and $rank(B)$ rank-one matrices, i.e. you use **point 1** above. So you write

$$A=A_1 + A_2 +\cdots + A_{rank(A)} \\B=B_1 + B_2 +\cdots + B_{rank(B)}$$

From there, we can write the matrix $A+B$ as $$M=A+B=A_1 + A_2 +\cdots + A_{rank(A)} +B_1 + B_2 +\cdots + B_{rank(B)}$$
and you can now use **point 2** above to conclude that, since the sum above is a sum of $rank(A)+rank(B)$ rank-one matrices (i.e. $n=rank(A)+rank(B)$), that therefore, $$rank(A)+rank(B)=n\geq rank(M)=rank(A+B).$$